# bind element to touchstart

Tags: jquery, html, css, touchstart

I am getting Error that `"Object has no method 'apply'... "`

i am simply binding touch event with element but i am getting error object has apply method.

```
var clickEventType=((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');
$("#myImageFlow ").bind('touchstart',".sliderImage",abc);
function abc()
{}
```

I tried ,

```
var clickEventType=((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');
$("#myImageFlow ").bind('touchstart',".sliderImage");
```

this one also not working?? what to do? what changes should i make? I just want to bind element to `touchstart`.

Comment: Are you calling jQuery correctly?

Comment: @chiefGui yes i have checked ..

Answer (score 1):

```
var clickEventType = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

$("#myImageFlow ").on(clickEventType, '.sliderImage', abc);

function abc() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: not working , with this myonclick doesnt work in android tablet

Comment: Did you try just binding both `$("#myImageFlow ").on('click touchstart', '.sliderImage', abc);`

Comment: yes ....  if i print alert something inside function  then everything worke fine , i dont want any aler but